# Handling Month-over-Month data in Regression Model

Tags: machine-learning, regression, predictive-modeling, data-cleaning

I have data similar to what you see in the picture. I want to use a RandomForest Regression model where I can use fields (excluding MONTH_END_DT and LOCATION_ID) to predict REVENUE_PER_UNIT. The idea/goal being that, if I know how many SERVICEABLE_UNIT_CNT I have, and the number of HAPPY, NEUTRAL, or ANGRY customers I have, I can predict the REVENUE_PER_UNIT.

My question is: considering I don't want to do a time-series analysis, would I drop the duplicates in this dataset (notice the highlighted fields are duplicates if you remove location and month end)?
[image: example data]

Comment: Hi Larry, Welcome  to the community. Please consider upvoting/marking the answer as correct if you find anything useful on your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should be removing the duplicates considering you would be dropping the month_end_dt and location_id column as well before feeding the data to the model.

Comment: Thank's @Kriti, my points are too low to upvote your answer, but I accepted it.

Answer (score 1):

I would consider not removing the duplicates, instead some light feature engineering by extracting the month of the year as a qualitative feature, as it's possible customer behaviour and sentiment is influence by given months.